# HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: http, servlets, web, http-status-code-404

I'm using tomcat7 server for my project. Today i combined some html pages to a directory called sp for managing purpose. When i enter the *http://localhost:8080/skypark/sp/upload*.htmladdress, upload page in sp directory will displays. 
But when i try to submit the contents it shows

**HTTP Status 404 - /skypark/sp/FileUploadServlet**

**description: The requested resource is not available.**

My directory structure is :

[image]

I don't know why it was showing this error

the servlet mapping for FileUploadServlet is:

```
<servlet id="spU">
<display-name>FileUploadServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>skypark.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping id="spUm">
<servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/FileUploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Before adding to **sp** directory upload.html worked well, files where uploaded normally. Please anyone tell me why it was showing this error...thanks.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<url-pattern>/sp/FileUploadServlet</url-pattern>
```

The pattern must be absolute starting **your webapp** context path. So, if your webapp is `skypark`, it must start from there.